# Update ListView when updates from another Class

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I am building simple app where It show all the files of certain format in one listview. I have divided program to class "DataFiles" where I establish FileSystemWatcher if something change there. If something change then I want to update my Listview which is placed in MainWindows.xaml.

So I have my MainWindowViewModel.cs and DataFiles.cs and ListView in MainWindow.xaml. How to update List from DataFiles to MainWindow.xaml?

My DataFiles class if something helps:

```
public FileSystemWatcher filewatcher;
    public string ConfigurationFilesSourcePath;
    public ObservableCollection<Files> fileslist { get; protected set; } = new ObservableCollection<Files>();

    public void InitializeFiles()
    {
        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher
        filewatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

        // Set filter
        filewatcher.Filter = "*.txt";

        // Set the path
        filewatcher.Path = ConfigurationFilesSourcePath;

        // Subscribe to the Created event
        filewatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileOnchanged);
        filewatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileOnchanged);
        filewatcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileOnchanged);
        filewatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(FileOnRenamed);

        // Enable the FileSystemWatcher events
        filewatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        RefreshFilesList();
    }

    private void FileOnchanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshFilesList();
    }

    private void FileOnRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshFilesList();
    }

    public void RefreshFilesList()
    {
        fileslist.Clear();

        //string[] getfiles = Directory.GetFiles(FolderLocation);
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(ConfigurationFilesSourcePath);

        string[] extensions = new[] { ".txt" };

        int nof = 0;
        foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles().Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower())).ToArray())
        {
            nof++;

            fileslist.Add(new Files()
            {
                FileId = nof,
                FileName = file.Name,
                FileChanged = file.LastWriteTime.ToString(),
                FileCreated = file.CreationTime.ToString(),
                OnlyNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name)
            });
        }

        NotifyPropertyChanged("fileslist");
    }
```

If you think that I must be pretty new in WPF, You're right :) So sorry if this is stupid question. Please for help.

XAML:

```
<ListView Name="lvfiles" Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding fileslist}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFiles}" DataContext="{Binding }" Style="{StaticResource ListView}">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView x:Name="gridFiles">
                                <GridViewColumn>
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox Tag="{Binding ID}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn x:Name="FileId" Header="#" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileId}" Width="Auto"/>

                                <GridViewColumn x:Name="FileName" Header="{inf:Loc ConfigurationsName}" Width="Auto">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBox  Text="{Binding FileName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource ListViewTextBoxes}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>

                                <!--<GridViewColumn x:Name="FileName" Header="{inf:Loc ConfigurationsName}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}" Width="Auto"/>-->
                                <GridViewColumn x:Name="FileCreated" Header="{inf:Loc ConfigurationsCreated}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileCreated}" Width="Auto"/>
                                <GridViewColumn x:Name="FileChanged" Header="{inf:Loc ConfigurationsChanged}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileChanged}" Width="Auto"/>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
```

Comment: you should provide your XAML aswell. did you use a binding?

Comment: Yes. I update post (sorry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mainmenu you should assign a handler to PropertyChanged event and inside it you can update the list.

```
DataDiles.PropertyChanged+= DataFiles_PropertyChanged;

public void DataFiles_PropertyChanged(/*...*/)
{
    //Refresh the list
}
```

For more exact code please edit your question and add the definition of your DataFiles class completely.
I hope it will help.

Comment: @esispaned Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: @esispaned no problem my friend. please send me the first line of your DataFiles class. I'll solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The binding of `ItemsSource` to the `ObservableCollection` automatically synchronizes the listview with the collection for every collection.Add/Remove/Clear method call. So I wouldn't recommend to fully remake the collection for every filewatcher event. (If you had 99 files and 1 file was added, you would get 1 collection changed event for the Clear call and 100 events for the 100 Add calls.) Instead you could try to transfer the changes described by the filewatcher events exactly to collection changes: filewatcher.Created --> collection.Add; filewatcher.Deleted --> collection.Remove; filewatcher.Renamed --> collection.Remove + collection.Add. But if the filewatcher misses a file being created/deleted your list would not realize the change. (In fact I wouldn't trust the filewatcher that far.)

Or (easier) you don't use `ObservableCollection` but just `ArrayList` as type of your `FilesList` property. Than no event is raised during the `Clear` and `Add` calls and you trigger the synchronization of the `ListView` by calling `NotifyPropertyChanged("fileslist")` once at the end of `RefreshFilesList` as you already do.

Be sure that the `DataFiles` class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and that the `DataContext` of your `ListView` is the `DataFiles` instance (ideally located as property in your view model).

Comment: I dont expected more than 10 files, so that is not an issue for me. Thanks anyway.